# How can a fixnum be added to a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

If I want a string of both words and numbers in ruby, such as `"worda, wordb, 12, wordc, 10,"`
do I need to first convert the number to a string ie. 
a = 12.to_s?

Answer (score 6):

## Possible ways to mix strings and integers

It depends how you want to do it :

```
["worda", 10].join(', ')
"worda, #{10}"
"worda, %d" % 10
"worda" + ", " + 10.to_s
"worda" << ", " << 10.to_s
```

all return `"worda, 10"`

[`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) and string interpolation will both call [`.to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) implicitely.

## String + Integer

```
"worda" + 10
```

Is a `TypeError`, though, because there's no implicit conversion with `+`.

Otherwise `"1" + 2` could be either `"12"` or `3`. Javascript accepts it and returns "12", which is a mess IMHO.

## String << Integer

Finally:

```
"worda, " << 10
```

is a valid Ruby syntax, but it appends the ASCII code 10 (a newline), not the number 10:

```
"worda, \n"
```

Comment: Also mutators could be mentioned here.

Comment: @engineersmnky: I added `<<` after having seen Ilya's comment.

Comment: @EricDuminil (what no interest in mentioning coercion `coerce` and implicit conversion `to_str`, `to_int`, etc. ) :) We too could be like Javascript (which I agree is a slightly confusing mess)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby requires (approx.) strings to be of the same type, like most reasonable programming languages.

You have 1 solution.

`"word" + 12.to_s` 
or
`"word #{12}"`

The second example is called string interpolation, and will call the method `.to_s` on any object passed in.

Comment: This is not explicitly true. `ruby` does offer implicit conversion to a `String` by defining `to_str`. e.g. `class Fixnum; alias_method :to_str, :to_s;end` then `"Word" + 12 #=> "Word12"` **(Not recommended and just for edification)**. Also `Numeric` utilizes `coerce` for similar reasons e.g. `class String; def coerce(other); [other,self.length];end;end;` then `12 + 'ABC' #=> 15` **(Again simply edification)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can do

```
"worda, wordb, #{num_1}, wordc, #{num_2},"
```